# In React axios.get is fetching the correct response.data but the console is not logging any response.data._id

Tags: javascript, axios, vite

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setLoading(true);
  axios
    .get(`http://localhost:5555/books/${id}`)
    .then((response) => {
      setBook(response.data);
      console.log(response.data);
      console.log(response.data._id);
      setLoading(false);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      setLoading(false);
    });
}, [id]);
```

This is my code to get the data from the books data base
in the first console log `console.log(response.data)` the console is logging

```json
data: {
  _id: '6539fb91dee8e9f4440d9bca', 
  title: 'Scarlet', 
  author: 'JamesHowlatt', 
  publishYear: 2000,
  __v: 0
}
```

but the second console log `console.log(response.data._id)` is logging undefined why?
i understand that the setBook State wont be updated immediately but why is the response.data._id undefined?

Comment: That looks like you might want to use `response.data.data._id`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

for better visualization try:

```
console.log(response);
```

there is probably a data object inside data object like this:

```
data: {
  data: {
    _id: '6539fb91dee8e9f4440d9bca', 
    title: 'Scarlet', 
    author: 'JamesHowlatt', 
    publishYear: 2000,
    __v: 0
  }
}
```

therefore to console.log _id you need to do:

```
console.log(response.data.data._id)
```